# ContextMenu header too small

Tags: android

The context menu header in my app is too small, in Android v.24. How can I fix this? In earlier versions it worked fine.

Here's the code I use to create the menu with

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
...
    menu.setHeaderTitle(contact.name);

    callText = callText + " " + contact.phone().label + " ("
        + contact.phone().formattedPhoneNumber() + ")";
    // 1. OPEN
    mi = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, CONTEXT_MENU_OPEN, R.string.context_menu_open);
...
```

etc.

[image]

Comment: Please post the xml file

Comment: I create the context menu through code, there's no xml for the context menu. I will add that code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the solution proved to be adding the following lines to the values-v24 styles.xml, which modify the base theme of my app. Note that the first entry is the fix for the wrong positioning of the context menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="ContextPopupMenuStyleLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu">
      <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="HeaderTextDark" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large.Inverse">
      <item name="android:textColor">#777</item>
  </style>

    <style name="Theme.FastDialerDefault" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"> 
        <item name="android:contextPopupMenuStyle">@style/ContextPopupMenuStyleLight</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearancePopupMenuHeader">@style/HeaderTextDark</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```